# SWIFT struct as a model with different property types ( to use in a tableview )

Tags: swift, uitableview, struct

I'm trying to populate a tableview using a struct as the model.

```
struct TestStruct {
let oneString: String
let twoString: String

func inputFunc() -> [TestStruct] {
 return [
 TestStruct(oneString: "apple", twoString: "orange"),
 TestStruct(oneString: "beer", twoString: "coke")
 ]
}

}
```

How do I add a UIImage type or any other different property type as a 3rd element of the array without altering the first 2 of them?

Comment: You add it as a property to the struct that is either optional or has a default value

Comment: In one array all elements have to be of the same type. If you don't want to change TestStruct, you can nest it in another struct. But for me it's currently not clear how your data structure will look like. Do you have first an array of TestStruct data and then an an array of something else, or can they be mixed up?

Comment: @Patrick_K The whole point to this is I have a tableview. Let's say I want it to display 3 cells. The first 2 cells will be the Strings, but the 3rd will be a UIImage without strings. So I'll want the last element of the array to be different from the first 2.

Comment: Thanks, I understood it so far. But I wanted to understand the pattern of your elements. Do you have first elements of type TestStruct and then one or multiple elements of type Image, or can it be completely mixed (TestStruct, TestStruct, Image, TestStruct, ...)? Are there maybe even other elements? This all might have influence on the data structure.